# Why numbers of mappers vary so much in Hive for insert overwrite

Tags: hive, apache-tez

I have a transaction enabled table called t1 and I am using Tez as execution engine.

I fail to understand why there is huge difference in query plan for these two queries. What should I do to tune this scenario?

1. select t.id, t.id_type 
   from t 
   limit 20;

--> Generating 10 map tasks.

2. insert overwrite table t2
   select t.id as id, t.id_type as id_type
   from t
   limit 20;

--> Generating 1100 map tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain#LanguageManualExplain-EXPLAINSyntax) command, it will provide information about what is being done exactly and show the files being read. Compare the command output for both queries. Probably it reads different files or doing something else.

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED select t.id, t.id_type from t limit 20;
```

vs

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED insert overwrite table t2 select t.id as id, t.id_type as id_type from t limit 20;
```